# How would one go about detecting citation fraud circles?

Tags: publications

By citation fraud, I am referring to a certain number of academics colluding to write bogus papers and reference each other.

I personally suspect the department chair at my alma mater of engaging in this behavior, which I also think is already prevalent in China as a result of government rewards, etc.
The advent of text generators probably makes it of a even more universal concern.

Are there any tools in common use detecting extensive mutual citation? I am thinking there should be some tool like [MOSS](https://inkforall.com/copy-editing/plagiarism-checker/moss-plagiarism-checker-online/) or [Turnitin](https://www.turnitin.com/) but for network analysis of citations. If such a tool does not exist, what would an appropriate algorithm for this look like?

Comment: Bogus papers and circular citations aren't the same thing. Salami slicing results and circular citations might go together, though. But the quality of the resulting publication(s) should override other considerations.

Comment: The department chair I mentioned has a bogus paper referencing other similar bogus papers with suspiciously re-occurring authors. I am just hoping it's my own ignorance about some niche field although I highly doubt it, since the guy only has an h-index=6. So I am trying to figure out how to follow my gut feeling

Comment: Bogus papers seems to imply a bogus journal. Those are moderately well tracked.

Comment: Not necessarily. One can publish to IEEE journals with legitimate seeming language and made-up data for example

Comment: That would be a much (much) more serious infraction than citation circles or even salami slicing.

Comment: Right, but besides going after it at a content level, how would one demonstrate dishonesty in terms of collusion with authors doing the same thing? Is there even a name for it?

Comment: This question is asking about a lot of things. "Citation fraud circles" is not the same as "bogus papers" nor your comment about China and text generators. VTC as needs focus.

Comment: This is a bit of an X/Y problem. What you should focus on instead is evaluating researchers in a different way that is less susceptible to being gamed by citation cartels.

Answer (score 3):

With regard to the part of your question about "tools", the following, highly readable, paper describes one such tool.

- Ioannidis JPA, Baas J, Klavans R, Boyack KW (2019) A standardized citation metrics author database annotated for scientific field. PLoS Biol 17(8): e3000384. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pbio.3000384

It also discusses citation problems that are more general than the issue of unethical self-citation.